# How to Display Blob PDF data from mysqli database to your html PHP table

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, blob

I have here a free to error code on how to display all your data from database to an html table through php, but instead of only displaying characters and numbers, I also want to display BLOB data such as Pdf, Image, Txt and much more, can you guys pls help me how, btw im new to php and mysqli, $row[10]  is the field that i set to BLOB data type, thanks in advance guys, i love you all!!

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "recordmain_db" ;

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM recordmain_table");


  echo "<center><table id=myTable table border=8 cellspacing=1     
  cellpadding=5>";

  echo "<tr class='header'>

       <th>Doc Type</th>
       <th>Doc Date</th>
       <th>Date Sent</th>
       <th>Medium of Transaction</th>
       <th>Description</th>
       <th>Receiver</th>
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>Contact</th>
       <th>Attachment</th>
       <th>File</th>

       </tr>";
  ?>



  <?php


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

   {

 echo 

 "<tr>


      <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>    

      <td> " . $row[2] . "</td>

      <td>" . $row[3] . "</td>

      <td>" . $row[4] . "</td>

      <td>" . $row[5] . "</td>

      <td>" . $row[6] . "</td>

      <td>" . $row[7] . "</td>

      <td>" . $row[8] . "</td>

      <td>" . $row[9] .  "</td>

      <td>" . $row[10] .  "</td>


      </tr>";


      }

 echo "</table></center>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `base64_encode()` to display the blob data as pdf :

```
"<object data=\"data:application/pdf;base64," . base64_encode($row[10]) . " type=\"application/pdf\" ></object>"
```

Comment: Greetings Sir! I only put this one before you give me idea. <td>" . $row[10] . "</td>, but when i put inside echo this one, "<object data=\"data:application/pdf;base64," . base64_encode($row[10]) . " type=\"application/pdf\" ></object>" it doesnt show the blob data, but no error is comming out. Im sooo confuse now.

Comment: Could you try to enclose it with `iframe` tags, like : `<iframe><object> ... </object></iframe>` ?

Comment: I try to put it inside that <iframe> from <object data>....next to $rows [1] to[10], but it only give a blank frame, I can already add blob data in the database, but it only display as text or the name of the file that i upload, not a link that direct shows the file that i send such as pdf or image.

Comment: Is there any proper way to echo this inside the table??                                                            
  "<object data=\"data:application/pdf;base64," . base64_encode($row[10]) . " type=\"application/pdf\" ></object>"